# How to get floated div columns to fill container vertically

Tags: html, css, layout

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3epVw/2/

```
.floated_left {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    border: 3px solid red;
}

.floated_right {
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

I'd like the red boxed divs to fill the remaining space left within the wrapper div (green)

Left Column  might be bigger than Right Column , or visa versa, and i'd like the fill to happen in which ever scenario.

I'd also like Right Column 1 and Right Column 2 to fill as evenly as possible (rather than it all coming from Right Column 2

i'm new to css layouts and it's doing my head in trying to get it to work.

Comment: Have you tried putting the red ones in their own wrapper, and specifying the height for that wrapper?

Comment: I don't want to specify a height as all the contents will be dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job for [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

You'll need an intermediate wrapper, for the right and left columns.

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;           //this makes it a flexbox
    margin: 5px;
    border: 3px solid green;
}
.flex_wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;                //this makes each child element take up the same amount of space.
    flex-direction: column; //this makes the child elements stack vertically
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
.flex_column {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: center; //centers horizontally
    align-items: center;     //centers vertically
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3epVw/5/

Flexbox is widely supported by current browsers, but [there be dragons](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) if you need to support IE9 or below.

edited to add `align-items: center;` in order to center text vertically.